# Can't run android project for cordova 3.x version using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-3

I am new to Phonegap. I am trying to run android hello world app using cordova 3.4.x. but when I try to run app It's give an error (com.ert.ertt) Unexpectedly stop working. I am using eclipse. I have follow many tutorial but problem still remain. Please help me regarding this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Q: Out of curiosity, why Cordova 3.4.x instead of Cordova 4.x (the current version is 4.1.2)?

Comment: Hi FoggyDay, I posted this question 10 months before! So 3.4.x was latest at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new workspace in eclipse. I had the same problem and got fixed when i worked in a new workspace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have created new workspace in eclipse and try in it but problem still remains. Are you using cordova 3.x? because for phonegap 2.x. It's work fine.

Comment: Ya am using cordova 3.x

Answer (score 1):

For cordova there is chrome extension which will ease your task

Riple Emulator is chrome app for phonegap developers